# Get previous day in an Expression

Tags: date, sql-server-2005, types, ssis, ssis-2005

Just need help on this as I am new at SSIS. I got an expression but I want yesterday, not today.

```
 "Daily "+ (RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()),4))+(RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("mm",getdate()),2))+(RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("dd",getdate()),2))+".CSV"
```

Currently it looks like this

Daily 20161006.CSV

What I want is

Daily 20161005.CSV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
"Daily "
+ (DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(DATEADD("day",-1,GETDATE()))
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("MM", DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())),2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())),2)
+ ".CSV"
```

It looks like you are in Australia, so it is `20161006` there, but in US Right now, it is `20161005`, and see how it shows yesterday i.e. `20161004` in the file name when I clicked **Evaluate value**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shiva- Your answer is perfect. I marked your answer as correct too and yes I am in Australia :)

Answer (score 1):

`"Daily "+ (RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()),4))+(RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("mm",getdate()),2))+(RIGHT("0" +(DT_STR,4,1252) (DatePart("dd",getdate())-1),2))+".CSV"`

This should work.